# Orientdb - How do Filter a Match with an Edge Property

Tags: orientdb

Look the Match

```
    SELECT PSQ_psq_nome AS nome, INS_ins_nome AS instituicao, COUNT(PUB_pub_id) AS qtdpub, * FROM (
    MATCH 
       {class:Pais, as:PAI,  where:(pai_id=1)} <-NASCEU- {class:Pesquisador, as:PSQ} -PUBLICOU-> {class:Publicacao, as:PUB, where: (pub_data_publicacao_int > 20141231)},
       {as:PSQ} -ATUOU-> {class:Instituicao, as:INS}
    RETURN PSQ.psq_nome AS nome, INS.ins_nome AS instituicao, PUB.pub_id, PUBLICOU.ordem )

GROUP BY PSQ_psq_nome, INS_ins_nome
ORDER BY qtdpub DESC, nome
```

I need use the property ordem, type integer, for the edge PUBLICOU. Is it possible?

something like (see PUBLICOU)

```
SELECT PSQ_psq_nome AS nome, INS_ins_nome AS instituicao, COUNT(PUB_pub_id) AS qtdpub, * FROM (
MATCH 
   {class:Pais, as:PAI,  where:(pai_id=1)} <-NASCEU- {class:Pesquisador, as:PSQ} -PUBLICOU { where: (ordem = 1) -> {class:Publicacao, as:PUB, where: (pub_data_publicacao_int > 20141231)},
   {as:PSQ} -ATUOU-> {class:Instituicao, as:INS}
RETURN PSQ.psq_nome AS nome, INS.ins_nome AS instituicao, PUB.pub_id, PUBLICOU.ordem )

GROUP BY PSQ_psq_nome, INS_ins_nome
ORDER BY qtdpub DESC, nome
```

Comment: Hi, can you post your schema? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but you cannot use arrow notation, eg. you have to replace

```
 {class:Pesquisador, as:PSQ} -PUBLICOU-> {class:Publicacao ...}
```

with

```
 {class:Pesquisador, as:PSQ} .outE("PUBLICOU"){where:(ordem = 1)}.inV() {class:Publicacao ...}
```

You can also assign an alias to the edge and return it in the result set if you wish